# Calculating unique transformation for multiple images in folder

Tags: matlab, alignment, transformation

I'm currently working on an alignment script which aligns two images very well. Usually, I get a data set which contains over 50 images of cells. I normally calculate a transformation matrix (T) based on fluorescent beads. However, this T-matrix gave rise to polarization in unpolarized cells, indicating that the transformation is not optimal. Therefore I switched to another script, which calculates a T-matrix based on cells and not beads. This new T-matrix aligns almost perfectly for a fraction of the cells, but there is always a portion of the images which aligns not so good.
I would like to continue with the alignment on cells, because this script works much better than the alignment on beads. In order to have optimal T-matrix for each image, I would like to calculate unique T-matrices for each image couple. I'm not very skilled in Matlab so the solution I could think of did not work.

Below you can find the current script. It functions by creating variables of the images I want to align and assign them to im1 and im2 in the script:

```
    function [T] = alim(im1, im2, Tstart)
    %ALIM Determines the transformation between the cameras.

    im3=im2;
    if (nargin>2)
    im2=imwarp(im2, Tstart,'OutputView',imref2d(size(im1)));
    end


    optimizer = registration.optimizer.RegularStepGradientDescent;
    optimizer.MaximumIterations=500;
    metric = registration.metric.MattesMutualInformation;

    T = imregtform(im2, im1, 'affine', optimizer, metric);

    if (nargin>2)
    T.T=Tstart.T*T.T;
    end

    figure;
    imshowpair(im1,imwarp(im3,T,'OutputView',imref2d(size(im1))));
    end
```

I tried to incorporate a loop which imports all images from the folder sequentially and assign these to im1 and im2. However, the problems that arises is that the type of data changes from uint16 into cell, which can't be used for this type of transformation. One defines in the script the location of the folders 'CAM1' and 'CAM2' and the number of images in these folders ('imnum')

```
    for i:imnum
    x{i}=imread(strcat(link,'CAM1\',num2str(i),'.tif'));
    y{i}=imread(strcat(link,'CAM2\',num2str(i),'.tif'));
```

I would like to have your view on this problem and hopefully you can make some suggestions on how I can import the images in a folder in one go and keep the data type uint16. I'm always open for suggestions so if you have other ideas on how to solve my problem, I would love it if you shared them with me. If anything is unclear, please contact me with questions!

With kind regards,

Reinier

Comment: `x` is a cell array, where each element `x{i}` is a uint16 array.

Comment: So if I assign im1 to x{i}, it should do the transformation based on the uint16 data?

Comment: I don't know, I can't tell how you are trying to call the function.  `T = alim(x{i}, y{i}, tstart);` should work fine.

Comment: Indeed it works to some extent. However, it reads only the first image and uses that image to calculate the T-matrix. So, even though the I read multiple images inside the folder, only the first is used in a correct manner. I wrote a script in which imread the files as mentioned above and used x{i} and y{i} for im1 and im2 in [T]=alim(x{i},y{i},Tstart);

Comment: The script worked on a small data set and now generates a cell containing the transformations corresponding to each individual image. I would like to accept your answer, @Peter, but I can't see the checkmark to accept your answer. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: I will rewrite the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a cell array, where each element `x{i}` is a uint16 array.  Cell arrays can hold any other datatype, including more cell arrays, and are a great way to wrap collections of objects, especially when their sizes and/or types may differ.

In your case, just call your function like this:

```
T = alim(x{i}, y{i}, tstart);
```

Or, even better, put the output matrix into a similar cell:

```
T{i} = alim(x{i}, y{i}, tstart);
```